# Winrar Settings, Batchfile or any other possibility to Monitor and create Archives automated

Tags: windows, powershell, server, archive, winrar

i searched in Winrar Settings but coudn't the Settings which i need, is there anyway to Setup Winrar to Monitor a specific Folder, and every Folder that gets put in that specific Folder should be packed to a sperate Archive, i don't need any compression, the Archive has to have:

1. Same Name as the Folder
2. Size Should not be bigger then 0,99 GB (1.073.000.000 bytes) if Size is bigger then the Archive should be splitted in max. 0,99 GB (1.073.000.000 bytes) Parts
3. Every Archive Should be Password protected (Same Password for every Archive)
4. Is it also Possible to set a command like Put in Every Archive the Content which is located in C:\FolderX
5. After successful creating the Archvies only the created Archive/ Parts should remain the the Folders and rest should be moved to Recycle Bin

C:\FolderX [Every File which is here Should be Put in Every Archvie which will be created]

C:\MainFolder [Every Folder which is here should be created to an Archvie like]

C:\MainFolder\Folder1 = 500 MB -> Folder1.rar = 500mb Password = xyz

C:\MainFolder\Folder2 = 1500 MB -> Folder2.part1.rar = 0,99 GB, Folder2.part2.rar = 427 MB Password = xyz

C:\MainFolder\Folder3 = 3500 MB -> Folder3.part1.rar = 0,99 GB, Folder3.part2.rar = 0,99 GB, Folder3.part3.rar = 0,99 GB, Folder3.part4.rar = 281 MB Password = xyz

When the Archvies are extracted they Should be like just 1 Folder with the content Folder1\textfile1, textfile2 etc

/ NO SubFolders Like Folder1\Fodler1\textfile1, textfile2

Winrar should only run process at time the rest should be put in queue.

Can this be done with a Batchfile and use the Batchfile as a Windows Service?

My OS is Windows 2019 Standard, i hope you guys can understand my English.

best regards

jimboy

Answer (score 0):

WinRAR does not do that as it is for Windows, instead use RAR.exe (in the same folder as WinRAR.exe). The RAR manual is RAR.txt

RAR for Windows Command Line works with Batch files so can be tested and run from Windows by typing Cmd in the search bar.

It also works much better with the more advanced Windows Powershell.

PS. My RAR Command Line Secrets course will be available in 2021, you can  register for Priority access at bit.ly/RCLSw-rN for more information about this affordable course.